# Logic help, possibly regarding loops

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, logic

So for example, I have a list of items, let's say:

1. Apple
2. Oramge
3. Banana
4. Melon
5. Papaya

Now I have a limit of 3 items on my display. So say, if I want to display `Papaya`, then it must be on the 2nd slot and Melon should be on the 1st slot since there's a limit of 3.

```
+---+---------+---------+
| 1 | Apple   | Melon   |
| 2 | Orange  | Papaya  |
| 3 | Banana  |         |
+-----------------------+
```

Now I'm having trouble turning this into code. Like, for example, If I want to get what slot `Banana` should be, I should be able to get `3`. If I want to know what slot `Melon` should be, I'll get `1`. Can anyone help me out? What do I need to do in order to convert this idea to code form.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with vb.net to write an actual answer, but it's going to involve a [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your array and slots are both zero-based, you can get the slot with a simple calculation:

```
slot = arrayindex mod numslots
```

It becomes a little more complicated if your array is one-based but you fix that simply by subtracting 1 before the modulus operation:

```
slot = (arrayindex - 1) mod numslots
```

And, if your *slots* are one-based, simply add 1 to `slot` in both cases above.

```
slot = (arrayindex mod numslots) + 1
slot = ((arrayindex - 1) mod numslots) + 1
```

So, for example, let's assume one-based arrays and zero-based slots (three of them, 0 through 2), papaya has an index of 5. Using:

```
slot = (arrayindex - 1) mod numslots
slot = (    5      - 1) mod    3
slot =          4       mod    3
slot =                 1
```

hence it would go in the second slot.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation, that worked very well. I'm regretting not paying too much attention in math lessons.

Answer (score 0):

How about modular arithmetic using the `MOD` operator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz(v=vs.80).aspx)

```
slot = (index_of_item MOD items_on_display) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code

```
column = 0
row = item_number
while row > max_rows
    row = row - max_rows
    column = column + 1
```

Once this is run, row and column will be set to the correct (0 based) loctions. You can implement more efficiently using the mod operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int k=0; k<totalFruits; k++)
{
 for(i=1; i<4; i++)
 {
  fruitNumber = i;
 }
}
```